# How to create a download link in shiny for a local excel workbook (not dataframe) via downloadHandler

Tags: r, shiny

ref: [How to download workbook via downloadHandler on Shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718424/how-to-download-workbook-via-downloadhandler-on-shiny)

** Workbook is already held in the app's directory**

Does anyone have experience with putting in a download link into a shiny app for an excel file held in the app's directory? I have an excel form that I need users to be able to download and use (it is specifically NOT a dataframe).

The following code worked for when I put in a powerpoint file in the downloadHandler function:

```
output$downloadinflationguidance <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste("www/inflation-guidance - ", Sys.Date(), '.pptx', sep='')
  },
  content = function(con) {
    pptx <- read_pptx("www/inflation-guidance.pptx")
    print(pptx, target = con)
  }
)
```

But when I swap out the powerpoint stuff for the excel form (see below) it doesn't work. When I run the app and click on the download link, the user gets an error saying "file not found". The excel file is held locally on the app in a folder titled "www". Am I missing a trick here?

```
shinyUI(
downloadLink("dl_excel_calc", label = "Excel Version")
)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$dl_excel_calc <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("indexation_tool_excel -", Sys.Date(), ".xlsx", sep='')
    },
    content = function(con) {
      xlsx <- read_excel('indexation_tool_excel.xlsx')
      print(xlsx, target = con)
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried including a literal `tags$a("my link", href = "www/file.xlsx")`? Or is the xlsx file generated on the fly?

Comment: If the file is generated on the fly, then you should not be creating it within the apps running directory, preferring `tempfile(..)` instead.

Comment: @r2evans The excel file was created outside of the app and then uploaded directly into the directory. Do I use the tags$a function instead of the downloadHandler, e.g. 

```
test1 <- tags$a("my link", href = "www/indexation_tool_excel.xlsx") 

output$tester <- renderUI({ 
tagList("", test1) 
}) 
```

Comment: yes, I think what you need ultimately is just `<a href="www/file.xlsx">hello world</a>`, which can be made using `tags$a(...)` as above.