Trouble generating report in excel via shinyapps
i'm trying to follow this guide and when i try to run it and click the download button it gives me an html file i don't know why. It's not only with this script, but in my personal project as well.
Here's the code:
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)

# create some example data to download
my_table <- data.frame(
  Name = letters[1:4],
  Age = seq(20, 26, 2),
  Occupation = LETTERS[15:18],
  Income = c(50000, 20000, 30000, 45000)
)

# add a totals row
my_table <- rbind(
  my_table,
  data.frame(
    Name = "Total",
    Age = NA_integer_,
    Occupation = "",
    Income = sum(my_table$Income)
  )
)

# minimal Shiny UI
ui <- fluidRow(
  column(
    width = 12,
    align = "center",
    tableOutput("table_out"),
    br(),
    downloadButton(
      "download_excel", 
      "Download Data to Excel"
    )
  )
)

# minimal Shiny server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table_out <- renderTable({
    my_table
  })
  
  
  output$download_excel <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "employee_data.xlsx"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      my_workbook <- createWorkbook()
      
      addWorksheet(
        wb = my_workbook,
        sheetName = "Employee Data"
      )
      
      setColWidths(
        my_workbook,
        1,
        cols = 1:4,
        widths = c(6, 6, 10, 10)
      )
      
      writeData(
        my_workbook,
        sheet = 1,
        c(
          "Company Name",
          "Employee Data"
        ),
        startRow = 1,
        startCol = 1
      )
      
      addStyle(
        my_workbook,
        sheet = 1,
        style = createStyle(
          fontSize = 24,
          textDecoration = "bold"
        ),
        rows = 1:2,
        cols = 1
      )
      
      writeData(
        my_workbook,
        sheet = 1,
        my_table,
        startRow = 5,
        startCol = 1
      )
      
      addStyle(
        my_workbook,
        sheet = 1,
        style = createStyle(
          fgFill = "#1a5bc4",
          halign = "center",
          fontColour = "#ffffff"
        ),
        rows = 5,
        cols = 1:4,
        gridExpand = TRUE
      )
      
      addStyle(
        my_workbook,
        sheet = 1,
        style = createStyle(
          fgFill = "#7dafff",
          numFmt = "comma"
        ),
        rows = 6:10,
        cols = 1:4,
        gridExpand = TRUE
      )
      
      saveWorkbook(my_workbook, file)
    }
  )

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

The error that appears in the console is this one:
Warning: Error in : wb must be a Workbok
1: runApp
But i've already checked and it's in the code my_workbook <- createWorkbook() so i don't know what could be wrong.
Result of sessionInfo():
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8    

time zone: America/Fortaleza
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] writexl_1.5.1      dplyr_1.1.4        xlsx_0.6.5         readxl_1.4.3       openxlsx_4.2.5.2   lubridate_1.9.3   
 [7] rbcb_0.1.14        DT_0.33            shinyWidgets_0.8.7 bslib_0.7.0        shiny_1.9.1        devtools_2.4.5    
[13] usethis_2.2.3     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] htmlwidgets_1.6.4 remotes_2.5.0     rJava_1.0-11      lattice_0.22-6    vctrs_0.6.5       tools_4.4.1       crosstalk_1.2.1  
 [8] generics_0.1.3    curl_5.2.1        tibble_3.2.1      fansi_1.0.6       xts_0.14.0        pkgconfig_2.0.3   lifecycle_1.0.4  
[15] compiler_4.4.1    stringr_1.5.1     fontawesome_0.5.2 httpuv_1.6.15     htmltools_0.5.8.1 sass_0.4.9        yaml_2.3.9       
[22] crayon_1.5.3      later_1.3.2       pillar_1.9.0      jquerylib_0.1.4   urlchecker_1.0.1  ellipsis_0.3.2    openssl_2.2.0    
[29] rsconnect_1.3.1   cachem_1.1.0      sessioninfo_1.2.2 mime_0.12         tidyselect_1.2.1  zip_2.3.1         digest_0.6.36    
[36] stringi_1.8.4     purrr_1.0.2       fastmap_1.2.0     grid_4.4.1        cli_3.6.3         magrittr_2.0.3    xlsxjars_0.6.1   
[43] pkgbuild_1.4.4    utf8_1.2.4        withr_3.0.0       promises_1.3.0    timechange_0.3.0  httr_1.4.7        cellranger_1.1.0 
[50] askpass_1.2.0     zoo_1.8-12        memoise_2.0.1     miniUI_0.1.1.1    profvis_0.3.8     rlang_1.1.4       Rcpp_1.0.12      
[57] xtable_1.8-4      glue_1.7.0        xml2_1.3.6        pkgload_1.4.0     rstudioapi_0.16.0 jsonlite_1.8.8    R6_2.5.1         
[64] fs_1.6.4


Your app works for me. When I click the button I download a proper xlsx file.  Try restarting your R session.

Same for me. Can you add the result of call of function sessionInfo() to your question ?

I got it fixed when i restart R. This script in specific is working fine, but it seems to be some problem with shiny and openxlsx, i'm trying to make a script that imports .xlsx file with two columns and with this input export another .xslx file with the sum of the two columns (and add a style for the last column) but it keep giving me this error. Is kinda the same problem with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948024/shiny-downloadhandler-openxlsx-does-not-generate-a-xlsx-file . I'll try to fix it again.

The script i'm trying to run is this one: https://www.invertexto.com/?n=Bf4I5ZL
The input is just an .xlsx file with two numeric columns. It gives me the same error.
